# flume data transfer monitor with file name

Tags: monitoring, flume, flume-ng

I am  monitoring flume using below command

```
flume-ng agent -n agent_name -c conf -f conf/config.conf \-Dflume.monitoring.type=http -Dflume.monitoring.port=34545\
```

I am not getting the file name.

How do I monitor both source and sink with file name and other details?

How do I store the result in db?